# Issue with Scrolling in prototype tableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

can anyone explain why the scroll view automatically scrolls up when selecting the stepper in some cells in the .gif this occurs when pressing 2p tuxedo (does not occur with all cells) below is code for view controller (Service1ViewController), code for the cell (Service1TableViewCell) and the code for the init function (Service)

I updated the code with the answer provided and this issue started to occur below is the updated code along with the updated .gif file.

[![updated issue][1]][1]

[image: UIScrollView Issue]

Service1ViewController

```
class Service1ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Service1IMG: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var service1TableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var service1Total: UILabel!



var Dry: [Service1] = []

var orderCount = [Int : Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Dry = Options()
    for i in 0...30// TotaL number of rows
    {
        orderCount[i] = 0 // DEFAULT order count will be 0
    }

}


func Options() -> [Service1]{

    var dryOptions: [Service1] = []

    let option1 = Service1(titled: "Pants", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option2 = Service1(titled: "Shirt", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option3 = Service1(titled: "Polo Shirt", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option4 = Service1(titled: "Polo (Long Sleeves)", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option5 = Service1(titled: "Shorts", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option6 = Service1(titled: "Tie", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option7 = Service1(titled: "2 Pc Tuxedo", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option8 = Service1(titled: "Jacket", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option9 = Service1(titled: "Men's 2pc Suite", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option10 = Service1(titled: "Blouse", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option11 = Service1(titled: "Skirt", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option12 = Service1(titled: "Women's 2pc Suite", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option13 = Service1(titled: "Dress", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option14 = Service1(titled: "Sweater", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option15 = Service1(titled: "Semi Formal Dress", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option16 = Service1(titled: "Customer Bag", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option17 = Service1(titled: "Jumpsuite", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option18 = Service1(titled: "Over Coat", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option19 = Service1(titled: "Rain Coat", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option20 = Service1(titled: "Skirt W/Pleats", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option21 = Service1(titled: "Robe", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option22 = Service1(titled: "Comforter /King", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option23 = Service1(titled: "Comforter /Queen", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option24 = Service1(titled: "Comforter /Twin", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option25 = Service1(titled: "Long Jacket", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option26 = Service1(titled: "Winter Jacket", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option27 = Service1(titled: "Men's 3pc Suite", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option28 = Service1(titled: "Women's 3pc Suite", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option29 = Service1(titled: "Overall", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option30 = Service1(titled: "Table Cloth/Small", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))
    let option31 = Service1(titled: "Shawl", pricing: 5.29, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DryCleaning"))

    dryOptions.append(option1)
    dryOptions.append(option2)
    dryOptions.append(option3)
    dryOptions.append(option4)
    dryOptions.append(option5)
    dryOptions.append(option6)
    dryOptions.append(option7)
    dryOptions.append(option8)
    dryOptions.append(option9)
    dryOptions.append(option10)
    dryOptions.append(option11)
    dryOptions.append(option12)
    dryOptions.append(option13)
    dryOptions.append(option14)
    dryOptions.append(option15)
    dryOptions.append(option16)
    dryOptions.append(option17)
    dryOptions.append(option18)
    dryOptions.append(option19)
    dryOptions.append(option20)
    dryOptions.append(option21)
    dryOptions.append(option22)
    dryOptions.append(option23)
    dryOptions.append(option24)
    dryOptions.append(option25)
    dryOptions.append(option26)
    dryOptions.append(option27)
    dryOptions.append(option28)
    dryOptions.append(option29)
    dryOptions.append(option30)
    dryOptions.append(option31)

    return dryOptions

}

}
extension Service1ViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
  @IBAction func stepperAcn(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    let cellPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: service1TableView)
    let indPath : IndexPath = service1TableView.indexPathForRow(at:    cellPosition)!

    orderCount[indPath.row] = Int(sender.value)

    service1TableView.beginUpdates()
    service1TableView.reloadRows(at: [indPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    service1TableView.endUpdates()
    //service1TableView.reloadData()

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return Dry.count


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Dry1 = Dry[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Service1Cell") as! Service1TableViewCell
    cell.setService1(Dry: Dry1)
    cell.quantityStepper.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.stepperLabel.text = String(orderCount[indexPath.row]!) // PASS VALUES TO LABEL
    cell.quantityStepper.value = Double(orderCount[indexPath.row]!) // PASS VALUES TO STEPPER

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}

// add function to collect (didSelectRowAt) and send selected data to cart
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)            {


}
}
```

Service1TableViewCell

```
class Service1TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var quantityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var quantityStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var Service1image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var serviceTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pricingInfo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepperLabel: UILabel!



func setService1(Dry: Service1){
    Service1image.image = Dry.service1image
    pricingInfo.text = Dry.service1Pricing.description
    serviceTitle.text = Dry.service1Title
}

//save data from each cell and multiply for total service


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Service

```
class Service
{
var title: String
var description: String
var image: UIImage



init(titled: String, description: String, image: UIImage)
{
    self.title = titled
    self.description = description
    self.image = image
}
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: my bad edited with code

Comment: try in device .

Comment: I tried in both simulator and device

Comment: how you set constraints for image and label below

Comment: I did not set constraints yet but I assumed this is not the issue because the issue occurs on the simulator running an iPhone 8 and I built the project using the iPhone 8 layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may rise from Reloading Whole TableView. Let's go with `reloadRows`

```
@IBAction func stepperAcn(_ sender: UIStepper) {

    let cellPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: service1TableView)
    let indPath : IndexPath = service1TableView.indexPathForRow(at: cellPosition)!

    orderCount[indPath.row] = Int(sender.value)

    service1TableView.beginUpdates()
    service1TableView.reloadRows(at: [indPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    service1TableView.endUpdates()

    //service1TableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: error still persists but not as bad as before, is their any way to make paging for the table view per cell so when you scroll each cel clips to the top constraint?

Comment: Check, any other reloadData() in ur coding

Comment: just did I removed the service1TableView.reloadData(), now when certain cells are in a certain position in the screen the cells below bounce down vertically

Comment: cellPosition CGPoint (x = 266, y = 314) this is when the new error occurs